Drag and drop of code lines in the notebook still does not work in JetBrains Jupyter notebooks
Drag and drop of code lines in the notebook still does not work in Jupyter notebooks, what can I do? The bug exists from around version 2023 (more than a year)
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-70068/Drag-and-drop-of-code-lines-in-the-notebook-does-not-work
The issue was updated 23 days ago but still was not fixed for more than a year.


"what can I do?" Use keyboard for now. Check Main Menu | Code | Move Line Up/Down as well as Move Statement Up/Down actions -- if they will work in Notebook (work in the actual/standard Editor).

@LazyOne What if I want to only move one word?

In such a case (only part of the line): Cut and Paste only I'm afraid. P.S. I personally hate using a mouse for moving the code -- too many "wrong"/accidental moves. In this aspect keyboard is more reliable. IMO of course.
